# connecting Arc 10.3 to a PostGIS database "the coordinate system identifier is invalid"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, postgis-2.0, arcgis-10.3

Has anyone had any success directly connecting Arc 10.3 to a PostGIS/postgres database, where the geometry type is 'geometry'?

I am able to connect and view the tables, but I am unable to view them - I receive the error from ArcCatalog "the coordinate system identifier is invalid".

I have created a geodatabase out of the data using 10.3 and a provisioning file to create sde.db_tune table, but that has made no difference (FYI, geometry_storage in db_tune is "PG_GEOMETRY"). Once I created the SDE tables, I attempted to connect using 10.2 but also received the same error message.

SRID is set per QGIS table properties (QGIS views the data perfectly, by the way).

I'm using PostGres 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1. I'm using extensions "postgis" and "postgis_topology" in my public schema, so minimal table massaging appears to be necessary (like manually updating geometry_columns).

Any ideas?

Comment: If you've been at this for months, you should have been talking with Esri Tech Support for months as well (the usual time from install to productivity is under an hour).  Please **edit** the question to contain the exact SRID value (with Well-Known Text) you been using.  The usual problems involve using a schema which is not the same as the user which is not the same as the login, so you should include this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (what are the chances on the day I post I find it?)

geometry columns were being created like:

CREATE TABLE tablename
(
  entity_id uuid,
  geometry geometry
)

when it should have been.

CREATE TABLE tablename
(
  entity_id uuid,
  geometry geometry(Point,4326)
)

once I made the change, geometry_columns was updated and I can now view the data using Arc 10.2 and 10.3